# How to detect keyboard click in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

In the picture below, I want to delete the tag when I press the backspace key.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvjFF.png)

but I don`t detect backspace event.

this is my code.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawKeyboardListener(
      focusNode: FocusNode(),
      onKey: (RawKeyEvent event) {
        print(event);
        if(event.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.backspace)) {
          print("press backspace");
          if(_tagsStringContent.length > 0) {
            if (_tagsStringContent.length == 1 && _showPrefixIcon == true) {
              widget.onDelete(_tagsStringContent[_tagsStringContent.length-1]);
              setState(() {
                _tagsStringContent.removeLast();
                _showPrefixIcon = false;
              });
            } else {
              widget.onDelete(_tagsStringContent[_tagsStringContent.length-1]);
              setState(() {
                _tagsStringContent.removeLast();
              });
            }
          }
          }
      },
      autofocus: true,
      child: TextField( (...skip)
      )
    )
  )
```

RawKeyEvent only works in computer backspace.

how to detect backspace key in keyboard?

Comment: Not sure what backspace is here but could it be `LogicalKeyboardKey.delete` you are looking for?

Comment: oops, sorry I upload the picture. @Ankan 
LogicalKeyboardKey.delete is not working.

Comment: I struggle with the same problem. Did you found a solution in the mean time?

Answer (score 0):

try to check this flutter package
https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_actions

Comment: I want to give an event to the existing backspace.